# Linear transformation, this qstn had fallen in CSIR net

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real polynomial of degree $<=10$. Let $Tp(x)= p'(x)$ for $p$ belongs to V be a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. Consider the basis ${1,x,x^2,....x^{10}}$ of $V$. Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis. Then
1) Trace A=1
2) det A=0
3) There is no m belongs to N such that A^m=0
4)A has a nonzero eigenvalue

Comment: Please post what you have attempted with regard to the solution.

Comment: Your title seems to say someone has fallen from a bridge or something  and needs to be rescued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $A$ is the matrix w.r.t the basis given.
The answer is $(2)$ 
The 1st colunm of $A$ is $0$, so $det=0$, in fact clearly the dimension of the **null** space is $>0$, as the dimension of the **range** space is clearly $9$, So (2) is true.

Clearly trace is $0$ so $(1)$ is false.

It can be converted into Jorden form by multiplying constants, hence it's characteristic polynomial is of the form $cx^{10}$, hence $A^{10}=0$ by calyey-hamilton theorem, hence $(3)$ is false, also characteristic polynomial has no non-zero root, hence $(4)$ is false.

Comment: How characterstick polynomial will be cx^10 , Can u explain in details plz